# Bootstrap 5 container sizes not maching documentation

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-5

I am learning Bootstrap 5 (familiar with coding, but new at web technologies).

I am making some HTML documents to learn how bootstrap behaves.

Today I was working on "containers" when I noticed they are behaving a little bit different than the documentation says.

Container sizes are not the same as in the documentation. Here is an example:

[image]

I know this is not a critical difference but... why is this happening?

I am using JavaScript functions to update those indicators

```
function getWindowWidth(){
    return window.innerWidth;
}

function updateContainerWidthText(className){
    let indicator = document.getElementById("element-width-indicator-" + className)
    let container = indicator.parentElement;
    let width = container.clientWidth; 
    indicator.innerText = `Container width: ${width}px`;
    
}

function updateDocumentWidthText(){
    let width = getWindowWidth();
    let indicator = document.getElementById("document-width-indicator");
    indicator.innerText = `Document width: ${width}px` ;
}

function updateSize(){
    
    updateDocumentWidthText();
    updateContainerWidthText("container");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-sm");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-md");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-lg");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-xl");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-xxl");
    updateContainerWidthText("container-fluid");
    


}

updateSize();

window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
```

And the HTML code is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    


    <h1>Container demo</h1>

    <div id="document-width-indicator"> indicator </div>
    
    <div class="container border "> 
        <h2> container</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 540px </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 720px  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 960px </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 1140px </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container-sm border "> 
        <h2> container-sm</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-sm"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 540px </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 720px  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 960px </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 1140px </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-md border "> 
        <h2> container-md</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-md"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 720px  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 960px </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 1140px </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-lg border "> 
        <h2> container-lg</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-lg"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        Es la opcion usada habitualmente.
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 100%  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 960px </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 1140px </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-xl border "> 
        <h2> container-xl</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-xl"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 100%  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 1140px </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-xxl border "> 
        <h2> container-xxl</h2>
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-xxl"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 100%  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 1320px </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid border "> 
        <h2>container fluid</h2> 
        <br>
        <div id="element-width-indicator-container-fluid"> indicator </div>
        <br>
        Abarca todo el ancho de la pantalla.
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li> <b>Extra small:</b> &lt 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Small:</b> &gt= 576px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>Medium:</b> &gt= 768px = 100%  </li>
            <li> <b>Large:</b> &gt= 992px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>X-Large:</b> &gt= 1200px = 100% </li>
            <li> <b>XX-Large:</b> &gt= 1400px = 100% </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- index.js -->
    <script src = "js/index.js"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that 2px difference was the border (1px line width). I removed it and everything seems fine now.